# msconfig - cannot save preferences (Windows 10 1703)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v1703, msconfig

Trying to edit system configuration this is what happens:

[image]
Translation from italian:

```
System configuration: impossible to save the original startup
configuration for a future restore. Modified settings will be undone.
Impossibile to access the file. The file is used by another process
```

I installed Windows 10 1703 through UEFI-NTFS with Secure boot disabled and then I enabled it.
I'm using an administrative account

**Edit.**
The problem was caused by the HIPS (real time intrusion protection system) of Eset Nod32. And that shows HIPS works great avoiding potential malicious software making changes to the system configuration.

Comment: Are you using any third-party security programs?

Comment: Did you try to run it with administrative privileges?

Comment: Yes I'm using Eset Nod32. And yes I've tried with admin. privileges but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the HIPS module of NOD32 antivirus. Well apparently it works great!

Comment: Can you be a little more clear? When you say “it works great!” are you being sarcastic? Did you discover how to save your configuration? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott See updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Disable 3rd party process/software, including anti-virus/security program(uninstall it if possible), then, re-start system and check the result.

Please confirm that if you can enable Clean Boot, if possible, re-start system in Clean Boot and try to change the MSCONFIG settings:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

Comment: This was partially correct. See my answer.